# Module.exports for unit-testing inside a route/controller

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, export, jestjs

I'm pretty new to NodeJS and unit testing.

I use `Jest`, but it should be the same "issue" with `Mocha` or `Ava`, or `whatever`...Because my problem seems to be about `export`/`import`...

I have a file `learning.js` with some functions

```
// learning.js

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

const multiply = (a, b) => a * b

module.exports = { sum: sum, multiply: multiply }
```

...and a `some.test.js` file:

```
// some.test.js

const { sum, multiply } = require('./learning')
// const { sum, multiply } = require('./another')

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
})

test('multiplies 2 x 2 to equal 4', () => {
  expect(multiply(2, 2)).toBe(4)
})
```

At this point, everything is perfect, my tests run and pass.

However, I've a third file named `another.js` structured that way (I use `express`):

```
router.get('/another', async function(req, res) {

  // TESTS
  function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }

  const multiply = (a, b) => a * b

  // DO SOME OTHER STUFF...

  res.status(200).send('ok')
})

module.exports = { sum: sum, multiply: multiply }
//module.exports = router
```

When I try to run the same tests from `some.test.js` (changing only the `require` statement to map to `another.js`), I can't make it works. My tests fail: `TypeError multiply is not a function`.

I tried to move `export`somewhere else, to rename some stuff with `dot.notation`... I can't make it work.

Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a scope problem -- your `sum` and `multiply` are out of scope from `module.exports`, since you're defining them from within your route handler.

Why not try this:

Create a new file `helpers.js` or `services.js` -- however you'd describe your functions.

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b

module.exports = { sum, multiply }
```

Then in your express file:

```
const helpers = require('./helpers.js')

router.get('/another', (req, res) => {
  helpers.sum(1,2)
  helpers.multiply(3,4)
  res.status(200).send('ok')
})

module.exports = router
```

Then in your test problem, you can require `helpers` in the same way and test the functions individually.

Comment: At first, it was my idea. But, I tried to stick to MVC, and if I do what you suggest, all my `logic` goes into `helpers.js` instead of my `controller`. I'm a newbie, but it seems weird to me... Is it normal? Do I not get what's a `controller`? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's fine, and it's not even against the spirit of MVC -- you may have heard the saying "fat models, skinny controllers". That's a big rails concept, but i think it's a good rule to follow for express as well. In my applications, my controller methods only talk to the models -- any logic is moved into helpers or handled in the model itself. In my opinion, moving logic outside route handlers is really beneficial -- makes it reusable if you need to use it again, and also allows you to see more clearly where/if you have logic issues.

Comment: I didn't know the saying "fat models, skinny controllers". I will look for it. Thx. But, for learning, is there a way to not use any `helpers.js`, keep all `logic` into my `another.js` and be able to unit-test all functions (fixing the `closure` problem) ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, same idea, just a different filename -- in `another.js`, write your functions, export them, and import them both into your route file and your test file.

Comment: Thanks. I will think about it. I do not have any `route` files (my `routes` are defined in my `controllers`). A bit disappointed :-) that one very specific `logic` (used only once) should be put into a `helpers` file...